# phabricator LDAP connection failed

Tags: ldapconnection, phabricator

I'm trying to configure LDAP authentification in Phabricator.

the setup on /config/group/ldap/have been done. However, when trying to login using LDAP, phabricator is answering tby the following error:

```
>>> UNRECOVERABLE FATAL ERROR <<<

Call to undefined function ldap_connect()

/sfrphabricator/phabricator/src/applications/auth/ldap/PhabricatorLDAPProvider.php:110


┻━┻ ︵ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ︵ ┻━┻
```

Is there any configuration trick for ldap authentification for phabricator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have another DN for your Anonymous Username, you have to check Search First and give all ldap "characteristics" for it.

Example :

```
    LDAP Hostname : yourLdapHostname.com
    Base Distinguished Name : OU=UsersEmea,DC=emea,DC=msad,DC=mycorp
    Search Attribute : sAMAccountName
    Check Search First
    Anonymous Username : CN=myanonymous,OU=otherservice,DC=emea,DC=msad,DC=mycorp
    Anonymous Password : <password of myanonymous>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the LDAP PHP extension. Usually, you can do this with something like:

```
apt-get install php5-ldap
yum install php-ldap
```

Comment: Thanks, i've rebuild with ldap and the lib ldapis ok. However, the configuration for the LDAP is not clear: Is the ldap.anonymous-user-name should be given with all the ldap characteristics or is it using the base DN provided in the parameter ldap.base_dn ? What is the difference between ldap.username-attribute and ldap.search_attribute ?